DBI failed: SCRAM authentication requires libpq version 10 or above
I am stacked on this error:
DBI connect('database=bigsdb_pseudomonas_isolates;host=localhost','apache',...) failed: SCRAM authentication requires libpq version 10 or above at test.pl line 23.
Failed to connect to database: SCRAM authentication requires libpq version 10 or above

test.pl is very simple:
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use DBI;


# Database connection parameters
my $db_driver = "Pg";
my $db_name = "myDB";
my $db_user = "apache";
my $db_password = "undef";
my $db_host = "localhost";

# Attempt to connect to the database
my $dbh = DBI->connect("DBI:$db_driver:database=$db_name;host=$db_host", $db_user, $db_password);

# Check if the connection was successful
if ($dbh) {
    print "Connected to database successfully!\n";
    # You can perform additional database operations here if needed For example: $dbh->do("SELECT * FROM your_table");
} else {
    print "Failed to connect to database: " . DBI->errstr . "\n";
}
# Disconnect from the database
$dbh->disconnect if $dbh;

I am on CentOS with:
pgsql-13, perl 5, version 16, perl-DBD-Pg-2.19.3-5.el7_9.x86_64 and
pg_config --version
PostgreSQL 13.15

Do you have any hints?
I am expecting to connect without SCRAM also because I changed to md5 the hba_conf of httpd.

If the password hash is stored using scram, then you can't use md5 no matter what the hba says.  You will need to reset the password (after changing password_encryption).

You apparently have multiple libpq libraries installed and DBI is picking the wrong one.  What version of CentOS is this, and how did you install all of that stuff?

Dear@jjanes, release is centos-release-7-9.2009.1.el7.centos.x86_64. About multiple libpq you are right since I have one /bin/psql --version psql (PostgreSQL) 9.2.24  and  one /usr/pgsql-13/bin/psql . I use the pgsql-13. I use yum install and if I do yum install libpq tells me conflict with postgresql-libs-9.2.24-9.el7_9.x86_64

@jjanes see my comment above

https://stackoverflow.com/users/1721239/jjanes do you have any hints? What about the LD_LIBRARY_PATH? ?

I would try just uninstalling 9.2 if you don't need it.  I tried to test this, but I don't have CentOS7 at hand.  I could get one on AWS, but its sshd won't recognize my private key so I gave up.  LD_LIBRARY_PATH might work, but would be a fragile solution.

Solved! 1) cpanm --uninstall DBD::Pg 2) set $PATH to include the binary of your psql and $LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/pgsql-13/lib 3) POSTGRES_HOME=/usr/pgsql-13 cpanm install DBD::Pg
